# Form validation on keypress jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function of jquery for validation, how can it be changed to use with keypress events  ?

```
function validate() {
        var stateID = $("#purpose").val();
            // var stateID = $(this).val();
        if (stateID == '') { 
              var validformula = true;
              var validweightq1 = true;
              var newpar = true;
              validformula = checkEmpty($("#formula"));
              validweightq1 = checkEmpty($("#weg"));
              newpar = checkEmpty($("#newparameter"));
                $("#btn-submit").attr("disabled",true);
              if(validweightq1 && validformula && newpar) {
                $("#btn-submit").attr("disabled",false);
                } 
        }
```

how to combine with on keypress ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#purpose').on('keypress', function(key) {})
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* make your function run when the `keypress` event is fired with:

```
$("#purpose").on('keypress', validate);
```

However, using the `keypress` event on a text input is generally a bad idea. It doesn't work on mobile devices, and it doesn't trigger when <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Delete</kbd> is pressed or text is pasted or cut in or out of the input. You should probably use the `input` event instead:

```
$("#purpose").on('input', validate);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#purpose').keyup(validate);
```